# How can i declare and define shared variables between header file in C?

Tags: c, filesystems, shared-libraries, header-files, sc

I have three source file called `supermercato.c` `cliente.c` `cassiere.c` and the following header file `cliente.h` `cassiere.h`. `supermercato.c` is where is `main()`. In `supermercato()` there I create two thread which are located in the other two source files but I have a shared structure and I don't know how to share all of these. Please can someone help me ?

```
 '''
    #include "librerie.h"
    #include "cliente.h"
    #define K 5 //numero totale di casse del supermercato
    #define C 20 //numero totale clienti
    #define UNIX_PATH_MAX 108
    #define SOCKNAME "./mysock"
    #define ec_meno1(s,m) \
    if((s) == -1) { perror(m); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }    
    #define ec_null(s,m) \
    if((s) == NULL) { perror(m); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    #define ec_zero(s,m) \
    if((s) != 0) { perror(m); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
     //these two
    int casse_aperte = 0;
    casse c[K];
    int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
//lettura file parametri
pthread_t tid_cassiere[K];
pthread_t tid_cliente[C];
//inizializza casse
for(int i=0;i<K;i++){
    c[i].num_clienti=0;
    c[i].q=NULL;
    ec_zero((pthread_mutex_init(&c[i].mtx,NULL)),"pthread_mutex_init failed");
    ec_zero((pthread_cond_init(&c[i].empty,NULL)),"pthread_cond_init failed");
    ec_zero((pthread_cond_init(&c[i].full,NULL)),"pthread_cond_init failed");
}
//apro una cassa
ec_zero((pthread_create(&tid_cassiere[0],NULL,cassiere,&c[0])),"pthread_create failed");
casse_aperte++;
//genero un cliente
for(int i=0;i<C;i++){
    //generare numero random [0,K-1] rand
    ec_zero((pthread_create(&tid_cliente[i],NULL,cliente,&c[0])),"pthread_create failed");
}
for(int i=0;i<C;i++){
    ec_zero((pthread_join(tid_cliente[i],NULL)),"join failed");
}
ec_zero((pthread_join(tid_cassiere[0],NULL)),"join failed");

return 0;
```

}

The following is `cliente.h`

```
   /** 
  Thread cliente
*/
//se K non e' stata definita ==> la definisco
 #ifndef K
   #define K 5
  #endif

typedef struct coda{
    int val;
    struct coda *next;
 }coda; 

 typedef struct cassa{
     int num_clienti;
     coda *q;
    pthread_mutex_t mtx;
    pthread_cond_t empty;
    pthread_cond_t full;    
 }casse;

 extern int casse_aperte;
 extern casse c[K];



void* cliente(void *c);
```

the following is `cliente.c`

```
  #include "librerie.h"
  #include "cliente.h"


 //funzione thread cliente
  void* cliente(void *c){
      //all'atto dell'entrata genero numero casuale [0,P]
      printf("CLIENTE\n");
      if(c == NULL){
         perror("invalid argument");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
      casse* cassa = (casse*)c;
      pthread_mutex_lock(&cassa->mtx);
       while(cassa->num_clienti != 0){ //in questo caso condizione mai verificata perche c'e' 
    solo un cliente
            //il cliente valuta se cambiare coda (ogni volta che si sveglia dopo la signal)
           pthread_cond_wait(&cassa->empty,&cassa->mtx);
      }
       cassa->num_clienti++;
       printf("cliente si accoda e produce un valore\n");

      pthread_cond_signal(&cassa->full);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&cassa->mtx);

        return NULL;
    }
```

And `librerie.h` is where there are all the standard libraries included

Comment: That's alot of code where most of it is not relevant to the question. Which variable(s) exactly do you need to "share"? It seems you should already know. For example: `extern int casse_aperte;` that variable is available in all the C source files if you include `cliente.h`. It's not clear what your exact problem is.

Comment: you're right, i'm sorry. I have a lot of confusion there... now I have one header file(the other one is irrelevant) whih contains the specific of cliente.h, I have to create another one for the other thread, but inserting extern variable in cliente.h is not make sense because the variable(s) is(are) used in both threads. So where i have to declare these variables as extern ? in the main file or one of the header files? and also the struct

Comment: " but inserting extern variable in cliente.h is not make sense because the variable(s) is(are) used in both threads". Why does it not make sense? Header files can be included by multiple different C files. So having `extern` variables in a common header file is fine.

Comment: because i insert it in the specific of cliente, so you suggest either to put them in one of the header files or to create another header with only these variables defined as extern? and of course include it on both the other header

Comment: It seems you are over-thinking this. Where you put the extern is almost a style choice. As long as the C file can see that extern no matter where it comes from then it will work. That is, you can put the extern directly in the C files where the variables need to be accessed or you can put it into one common header and include that everywhere or you can put it into seperate headers and include seperate headers in each C file. The result is functionally the same.